# Android File Transfer problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, backup, macos

I connect my Samsung S3 to my Mac and Android File Transfer says "Try reconnecting or restarting your device". I have restarted my phone and computer numerous times, uninstalled and downloaded AFT numerous times too but it's not making a difference.

I uninstalled and re-installed and uninstalled Kies again and that's not made a difference either.

What can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: You might want to try [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) to do the backups right on your device. After that, you can simply copy the backup to your computer to keep a copy there. Or have it backed up to the cloud, if you prefer that.